# Oracle APPS R12- AP Invoice Struck in re-validation

Tags: oracle-apps

Created an AP invoice with PO number and no holds placed and it has been validated. But it is struck in re-validation state. How to rectify this re-validation issue. Due to this I am unable to make a payment for this is invoice.

Needs - Revalidation status removal steps